# Why doesn't my son have admin permissions on the server I purchased him for Minecraft PE 0.8.1?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son is only 5, he just started playing Minecraft a week ago. I don't know anything about the game at all. I purchased a server for him through potpotsie so he's able to play with his friends and other people. He's able to access his server but it does not recognize him as the owner of the server. the admin or whatever you guys call it. I've tried asking other people, I've emailed the place I purchased the server from (with no answer, of course,) watched probably 50 youtube tutorials and I've googled until my fingers have turned red. I just don't understand what I'm doing or not doing correctly that it isn't recognizing him as the server admin. Any suggestions?

Comment: So there's admins (administrators) and ops (operators).  _You_ are effectively the admin since you purchased the server.  You can op your son, which is what you really want to do, since to admin the server means changing the settings of the game outside of the game itself.

Comment: on Minecraft PC edition, there's an "ops" file that you have to add the player name to to give them operator access. I've not played much PE but it might be worth checking if something like that exists.

Comment: I have NO idea what any of that means! I feel like I'm way in over my head, here. =/

Comment: The thing is, what I wanted to do, is change the game mode. He likes playing in creative and it's easiest for him since he's only 5 years old. I just don't understand how it would be able to recognize any player since there is no way to log in. What is it I'm missing here?

Comment: Right, according to their [knowledgebase](http://potpotsie.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/169189-about-my), you need to log into your panel for the server, go to the "OPs" tab, and add his username. Then he can use the "/gamemode creative" command to change the mode to Creative.

Comment: What username? There is nowhere on PE 0.8.1 that I'm aware of, to create a username? Thank you for taking your time to help me. :)

Comment: OH my GOSH thank you SO much!! You are a LIFESAVER! My son figured it out once I told him what you said. Thank you, thank you, thank you!! You are AMAZING!

Comment: I just check on my phone and you can change the player name under "Options" - [here](http://i.imgur.com/5hZ28iI.jpg) it's listed as "Steve" as default.

Comment: ah there we go :)

Comment: I understand that the problem has been solved but can I offer a solution that your wallet might like. It's a bit more advanced than just purchasing a server. Basically you run a server off of one of your computers (preferably a strong one) and port forward your router (internet connection). Basically what port forwarding does is it let's others temporarily connect to your internet and play on the server through a specific ip address. It's more advanced but it is definitely more cost effective. If you want more info just do some googling. You might need some general knowledge about modems.

Comment: @BakedPotato as the OP was not particularly technical or a Minecraft player, this would probably be a bit beyond them. For ease of management a hosted server is certianly the way to go although granted you have to make the price/manageability comparison.

Comment: @tombull98 That's true but it's always good to inform people about other options. Also judging that the post isn't only useful to the op but to others (hence the community protection), they might find it useful as well. I do however understand that the op might not be tech savvy enough to port forward.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a username under Options > Name. Once you've changed this you can add his name to the "OPs" panel in the PotPotsie control panel.